# What can be done to speed up this memoization decorator?

Tags: python, memoization

What I want is a memoization decorator that:

- can memoize instance methods with both arguments and keyword arguments
- has a cache that can be cleared (globally) with one call (vs. this one that uses a per-function cache: [python resettable instance method memoization decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431703/python-resettable-memoization-decorator))
- is reasonably efficient

I've tweaked an example I saw and came up with the following:

```
import functools

class Memoized(object):
  """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
  If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
  not re-evaluated.
  """

  __cache = {}

  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
    self.key = (func.__module__, func.__name__)

  def __call__(self, *args):
    try:
      return Memoized.__cache[self.key][args]
    except KeyError:
      value = self.func(*args)
      Memoized.__cache[self.key] = {args : value}
      return value
    except TypeError:
      # uncachable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
      # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
      return self.func(*args)

  def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    """Support instance methods."""
    return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

  @staticmethod
  def reset():
    Memoized.__cache = {}
```

My problem with it is that the caching part seems to involve a lot of overhead (eg. for recursive functions).  Using the following function as an example, I can call fib(30) ten times with the non-memoized version in less time than the memoized version.

```
def fib(n):

   if n in (0, 1):
      return n
   return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Can anyone suggest a better way to write this decorator?  (or point me to a better (ie. faster) decorator that does what I want).
I'm not interested in preserving method signatures, or helping introspection tools "know" anything about the decorated function.

Thanks.

P.S.  Using python 2.7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not actually caching any data, because each time you set a new cached value you overwrite the previous:

```
Memoized.__cache[self.key] = {args : value}
```

eg.

```
import functools

class Memoized(object):
    """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
    not re-evaluated.
    """

    cache = {}

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.key = (func.__module__, func.__name__)
        self.cache[self.key] = {}

    def __call__(self, *args):
      try:
          return Memoized.cache[self.key][args]
      except KeyError:
          value = self.func(*args)
          Memoized.cache[self.key][args] = value
          return value
      except TypeError:
          # uncachable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
          # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
          return self.func(*args)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        """Support instance methods."""
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

    @staticmethod
    def reset():
        Memoized.cache = {}
```

- fib(30) without caching: 2.86742401123
- fib(30) with caching: 0.000198125839233

Some other notes:

- Don't use `__prefix`; there's no reason to here and it only uglifies the code.
- Instead of using a single, monolithic, class-attribute dict, give each instance of `Memoized` its own dict, and keep a registry of `Memoized` objects.  This improves encapsulation, and removes the oddity of depending on the module and function names.

.

```
import functools
import weakref

class Memoized(object):
    """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
    not re-evaluated.

    >>> counter = 0
    >>> @Memoized
    ... def count():
    ...     global counter
    ...     counter += 1
    ...     return counter

    >>> counter = 0
    >>> Memoized.reset()
    >>> count()
    1
    >>> count()
    1
    >>> Memoized.reset()
    >>> count()
    2

    >>> class test(object):
    ...     @Memoized
    ...     def func(self):
    ...         global counter
    ...         counter += 1
    ...         return counter
    >>> testobject = test()
    >>> counter = 0
    >>> testobject.func()
    1
    >>> testobject.func()
    1
    >>> Memoized.reset()
    >>> testobject.func()
    2
    """

    caches = weakref.WeakSet()

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}
        Memoized.caches.add(self)

    def __call__(self, *args):
      try:
          return self.cache[args]
      except KeyError:
          value = self.func(*args)
          self.cache[args] = value
          return value
      except TypeError:
          # uncachable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
          # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
          return self.func(*args)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        """Support instance methods."""
        return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

    @staticmethod
    def reset():
        for memo in Memoized.caches:
            memo.cache = {}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Edited: add tests, and use weakref.WeakSet.  Note that WeakSet is only available in 2.7 (which the OP is using); for a version that works in 2.6, see the edit history.

Comment: Oh. Bother, you're right. I should've noticed that. :-) My version would still be faster, but not by nearly so much.

Comment: This doesn't really address the performance issue.  The OP's version *does* cache one item and he was testing it by calling the function repeatedly with the same argument, which is cached even without this change.

Comment: @Glenn:  Thanks!  No wonder my version was so slow!  There is a slight problem with the reset (which I'm sure existed in my version as well).  the "Memoized.cache" invokes Memoized.__call__ recursively until it gets a KeyError: ('__main__', 'fib').

Comment: @Andrew: No, he was calling a *recursive* function; this does address the issue.  @Gerrat: That doesn't happen for me in 2.6.  Maybe that's new in 2.7; if so, I'd categorize that as backwards-compatibility braindamage (which Python is unfortunately rather well-known for).

Comment: @Andrew:  I'm not exactly sure yet why it's faster (I thought my version was caching something); but Glenn's version (as well as Omnifarious's) is indeed much faster for the same fib function (hardly any overhead at all now).

Comment: @Gerrat: It's faster because you're testing on a doubly-recursive function; caching it turns it from an O(n^2) function to an O(n) one, as each nested call is itself cached.

Comment: @Glenn I'm aware that it is recursive, but even then his version caches the argument it was called with and another call with the same argument will return that cached value.  OP is happy so it doesn't matter, but you can try `fib(30); fib(30)` with Gerrat's code and see the benefit of cache.

Comment: @Glenn:  Thanks again!  I've never actually used weakrefs before, so maybe I'll look into them a bit now.  I *think* the third line of the reset should be: "If memo is *not* None"; but it doesn't seem to "purge" the cache anyway - calling the memoized fib function ten times and calling Memoized.reset() between each call still returns the result nearly instantaneously.  ...it's not recomputing each time.

Comment: @Gerrat: I tested resetting (in 2.6) and it did work.  The value of the weakref will be None if the object no longer exists; that code removes the old, dead `Memoized` weakref from the `Memoized.caches` set.  (That only happens if memoized functions are discarded.)  Don't test by timing (it'll be nearly instantaneous anyway); just add debug output to `fib`.  (I think this could be simplified with WeakSet; I'll do that after I test it.)

Comment: @Glenn: I was testing by timing (calling fib(31) took about 1 sec on my machine without memoization, but was nearly instantaneous when calling Memoized.reset() between each call.  I've changed to add debug output in fib, and now I'm sure it's not being reset in between calls - no output in fib calls with reset in between.  The debug output only appears the very first time it's being memoized.

Comment: @Gerrat: I'm not sure what you're comparing.  The first call to fib(30), with nothing previously memoized, should take on the order of 0.0001 seconds.  I added some doctests.

Comment: @Glenn:  Thanks again!  This works great.  My timing of the fib function is still bizarre (way longer), but I'll posit another question about that mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that is significantly faster. Unfortunately `reset` can no longer actually completely clear the cache since all the instances are storing their own local copy of the reference to the per-function dictionary.  Though you can sort of get it to work:

```
import functools

class Memoized(object):
  """Decorator that caches a function's return value each time it is called.
  If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned, and
  not re-evaluated.
  """

  __cache = {}

  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
    key = (func.__module__, func.__name__)
    if key not in self.__cache:
      self.__cache[key] = {}
    self.mycache = self.__cache[key]

  def __call__(self, *args):
    try:
      return self.mycache[args]
    except KeyError:
      value = self.func(*args)
      self.mycache[args] = value
      return value
    except TypeError:
      # uncachable -- for instance, passing a list as an argument.
      # Better to not cache than to blow up entirely.
      return self.func(*args)

  def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
    """Support instance methods."""
    return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

  @classmethod
  def reset(cls):
    for v in cls.__cache.itervalues():
      v.clear()
```

Comment: reset needs to be a @classmethod, then `reset(cls)`, and `cls.__cache.itervalues()`

Comment: @Nickpick - Clearly, in my rush to write it so many years ago, I didn't fully test it.