# python resettable memoization decorator (for a certain instance)

Tags: python, decorator, memoization

This question is a followup on the answer for [python resettable instance method memoization decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431703/python-resettable-memoization-decorator) . 
In fact, I would write this as a comment to that answer but I do not have (yet, I hope) enough reputation.

In that answer, @aix gives a nice approach to resetting memoized functions using decorators.

The "problem" with that answer is that calling `reset` for a certain decorated method resets the cache for all instances. An example using the same classes defined by @aix should make it clear:

```
c = my_class()
print c.my_func(55)
# This time the function is computed and stored in cache
print c.my_func(55)
# This second call is cached...  no computation needed
d = my_class()
d.my_func.reset()
print c.my_func(55)
# This third call is also computed, since the cache has been cleared
```

I think that `d.my_func.reset()` should only clear the cache for precomputed values of `d.my_func` and not for all other instances of `my_class`.

I have a semi-solution that does not convince completely but I guess that someone could improve.

I have modified the `reset()` method and introduced a parameter `instance`:

```
  def _reset(self,instance):
  for cached in self.cache.keys():
      if cached[0] == instance:
          del self.cache[cached]
```

Now if I do:

```
c = my_class()
print c.my_func(55)
# This time the function is computed and stored in cache
print c.my_func(55)
# This second call is cached
d = my_class()
d.my_func.reset(d)
print c.my_func(55)
# Now this third call is cached
```

However, the way to call the reset method: `d.my_func.reset(d)` seems (at least) ugly, but I have not been able to find a better solution... Does anyone have some idea?

Thanks!

**Edit**

For the record: instead of passing instance as a parameter, you can get the same behavior modifying the `__get__` method of the decorator.

Add `self.original_self = obj` in the `__get__(self, obj, objtype)` method and substitute `if cached[0] == instance` with `if cached[0] == self.original_self` in the `_reset` method. This solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__self__` attribute of the method (in this case, `self.__self__`) to find the class instance that it's bound to (instead of having to pass the instance as well).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since the method is decorated, if in my code I substitute `if cached[0] == instance` with `if cached[0] == self.__self__` I get `'memoized2' object has no attribute '__self__'`

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond... I think that I have a reasonable solution (see edit of question).

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities - which also store inside the instance `__dict__` instead of a global memo dict :

```
def MemoMeth(meth):
    """Memoizer for class methods (uses instance __dict__)
    Example:
    class C:
        @MemoMeth
        def slowmeth(self, a, b): ...
    """
    class _MemoMeth:
        def __init__(self, this):
            self.this = this
        def __call__(self, *args):
            memo = self.this.__dict__.setdefault(_MemoMeth, {})
            try:
                return memo[args][1]
            except:
                memo[args] = tr = time.time(), meth(self.this, *args)
                return tr[1]
        def reset(self):
            self.this.__dict__.setdefault(_MemoMeth, {}).clear()
    return property(_MemoMeth)
```

This one uses a thread-local-storage instead of a new wrapper object for each access:

```
def MemoMeth3(meth):
    """Memoizer for class methods (uses instance __dict__)
    Example:
    class C:
        @MemoMeth3
        def slowmeth(self, a, b): ...
    """
    tls = threading.local()
    class MemoProperty(object):
        def __call__(self, *args):
            memo = tls.instance.__dict__.setdefault(self, {})
            try:
                return memo[args][1]
            except:
                memo[args] = tr = time.time(), meth(tls.instance, *args)
                return tr[1]
        def reset(self):
            tls.instance.__dict__.setdefault(self, {}).clear()
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
            tls.instance = instance
            return self
    return MemoProperty()
```